# TouchID with Xcode 7, Swift 2

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9, touch-id

I can't figure out how to use TouchID with Xcode 7 using Swift 2. Here's the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let auth = LAContext()
    var authError: NSError?

    auth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError)

    }
```

This should work in iOS 8, but not in Xcode 7 Beta for iOS 9 development. It gives this compiler error: "Extra Argument 'error' in call", and "&authError" is highlighted. When I remove the extra argument, I get the compiler error: "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2 Apple introduced new mechanism for error handling.
If you take a look on method declaration you will see this:

```
func canEvaluatePolicy(policy: LAPolicy) throws
```

It doesn't have `error` parameter, but it has special word `throws` that tells you about potential error that can be thrown.

To handle such error use `do/try/catch` expression:

```
do {
    try auth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)
} catch {
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    try auth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics) 
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Just make sure to handle the error.

Comment: Like this?: ' override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let auth = LAContext()
        var authError: NSError?
        
        do {
        auth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        }'                                                                                                                  Because I get a compiler error: "Call can throw, but is not marked with "Try""

Comment: You need to add try before the line.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 You don´t need the var authError: NSError? any more, so just delete it, otherwise your fine.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks, I added it. The compile would also suggest that.

Comment: After adding try and deleting the authError variable I'm not getting any more compiler errors, thanks. By the way, how would I reference this in an 'if' statement? As in, if the user has an iOS Device with TouchID do this, else do something else such as display a passcode entry view?